# createrepo for remote rpm file: no package available

Tags: centos, repository, yum

Due to some situations, only one server (main server) can access internet and others connect to this server using vlan. So I want to create a repo in this server to install the following rpm:

http://downloads.eucalyptus.com/software/eucalyptus/4.1/centos/6/x86_64/eucalyptus-release-4.1.el6.noarch.rpm

I installed vsftpd on my main server and download the rpm file to the ftp folder, then run the following to createrepo:

createrepo /var/ftp/pub/localrepo/

Then I added the repo to my client server, but the following error exists when I install the eucalyptus package:

No package eucalyptus-cc available.

Any ideas?

Comment: The eucalyptus-release package configures a repository on the machine that installs it from which the other eucalyptus packages can be installed. If you are trying to *be* that repo then you don't need *that* package you need the *other* packages (the ones in the eucalyptus repository) on your repo host.

Comment: Thanks Etan. But how to find the other packages? Are they rpm file?

Comment: The other eucalyptus packages are going to be rpm files yes. They will be in the repository that the eucalyptus-release package configured for you. Have you installed eucalyptus-release anywhere? If you install *that* on your repo host you could use `yumdownloader` or `reposync` or `repotrack`, etc. to fetch the rpms from the added eucalyptus repository and put them in your ftp repository.